# Conversion to Swift 2 NSIndexPath error

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout, nsindexpath

Problem: Upon converting to Swift 2 I get the following error: "Value of optional type [NSIndexPath]? not unwrapped, did you mean to use "!" or "?"". The issue is that if I use '?', it gives an error saying I should use '!', and if I use '!' it gives an error saying I should use '?'. Thus it creates this nasty little bug loop that seems to be unfixable.

Code:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == Constants.SegueIdentifier {
        if let selectedRowIndex = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems().last as? NSIndexPath {
            if let cell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(selectedRowIndex) {
                //We check if the selected Card is the one in the middle to open the chat. If it's not, we scroll to the side card selected.
                if cell.frame.size.height > cell.bounds.size.height {
                    return true
                } else {
                    collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(selectedRowIndex, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

I haven't been able to come up with any work arounds since it seems like I need to somehow unwrap it. Has anyone seen this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
if let selectedRowIndex = collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!.last! as? NSIndexPath
```

My only concern is type safety but it works in my project as it currently is.

Comment: Your solution is not safe. Try the syntax in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

`indexPathsForSelectedItems()` returns `[NSIndexPath]?` (optional), you have to add another question mark for optional chaining and remove `as? NSIndexPath` as the compiler knows the unwrapped type.

```
if let selectedRowIndex = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.last {
```

Comment: When I try   if let selectedRowIndex = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.last as? NSIndexPath {    I get the following error: "Downcast from 'NSIndexPath?' to 'NSIndexPath' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?